# How to generate 8 bit unsigned PCM code comma separated

Tags: converter, pcm

Does anyone know if the audacity is capable of generating 8 bit unsigned PCM code comma separated or just 8 bit unsigned PCM code that are represented as bytes/number values?
If not, any clues on which program is capable of this?
I have designed a board that is capable of playing sound via PCM and thought it would be an easy job to find a converter program from wav to pcm.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
ffmpeg -i original-file.wav -f u8 -acodec pcm_u8 8bit-file.pcm
```

[See also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854513/can-ffmpeg-convert-audio-to-raw-pcm-if-so-how).

It's not comma-separated but binary, but that's definitely the more sensible choice – especially for a board with very limited bandwidth.

Answer (score 1):

Do this in two steps. First generate the RAW file (in audacity, there is an option to export to headerless RAW audio file under Export -> Export Audio). Make sure you export to 8-bit signed or unsigned values.

Then, using a linux tool called xxd, you convert the binary file into a c header file(I suppose you could do this with any hex viewer but I haven't tried). The header file has comma separated hexadecimal values of all samples of the audio in an array. You can copy from the array, and using a little scripting, convert those hexadecimal values into any representation.

Here is the format that `xxd -i input.raw` outputs by default:

```
unsigned char hel_raw[] = {
  0x7e, 0x7e, ......
};
unsigned int hel_raw_len = 2555;
```